# SQL Server Stuck to understand find and replace value in xml

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below code find text by this name "Segment Detail". If found then change the old xfundcode with new xfundcode. So many charindex which create confusion for me. please some one help me to understand mention below area with easy example.

Especially this area is not clear

```
 stuff(@oldGroupKeyvalue, 
 --starting from position of 2nd ~ +1
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1,
 --as many characters as exist between 3rd ~ and 2nd ~ (excluding ~)
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1)-1-
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1),
 --stuff the new xfundcode
 @newXfundCode
 );
```

Full code

```
 DECLARE @xml xml
 DECLARE @li varchar(max) ='Segment Detail'
 DECLARE @newXfundCode varchar(max) ='TEST'
    
 CREATE TABLE #tmpData (id INT, xmldata xml)  
    
 INSERT INTO #tmpData (id, xmldata) 
 VALUES (1,N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
 <PWR_ViewAll>
 <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
   <Section_x0020_>ZB-P1</Section_x0020_>
   <LineItem>B. Riley FBR Inc.</LineItem>
   <Revise_x0020_Date>08-21-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
   <GroupKey>Consensus Model~Total Revenue~TRIN~NBM~~1~ZB-P1</GroupKey>
 </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
 <dgvViewAll_Vertical>
   <Section_x0020_>CL</Section_x0020_>
   <LineItem>Deutsche Bank</LineItem>
   <Revise_x0020_Date>02-28-2020</Revise_x0020_Date>
   <GroupKey>Segment Detail~Total Revenue~RD_100~NBM~~1~CL</GroupKey>
 </dgvViewAll_Vertical>
 </PWR_ViewAll>')
    
 SELECT @xml = xmldata 
 FROM #tmpData 
 WHERE ID = 1
    
 DECLARE
     @oldGroupKeyvalue varchar(100), 
     @newGroupKeyValue varchar(100);
    
 SELECT @oldGroupKeyvalue = col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
 FROM @xml.nodes('/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical') AS tab (col)
 WHERE CHARINDEX(@li, col.value('(GroupKey/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>0;
    
    
 --@newGroupKeyValue = @oldgroupkeyvalue but stuff/"replace" string between 2nd&3rd ~ with @newXfundCode
 SELECT @newGroupKeyValue = 
 --"replace/stuff" the old xfundcode := all chars from position of 2nd ~ (+1) till position of the 2nd ~ (minus 1) with an empty string
 STUFF(@oldGroupKeyvalue, 
 --starting from position of 2nd ~ +1
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1,
 --as many characters as exist between 3rd ~ and 2nd ~ (excluding ~)
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1)+1)-1-
 charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, charindex('~', @oldGroupKeyvalue, 1)+1),
 --stuff the new xfundcode
 @newXfundCode
 );
    
 --test
 SELECT @oldGroupKeyValue AS oldgroupkeyvalue, @newGroupKeyValue AS newgroupkeyvalue;
    
 --test
 SELECT @xml AS oldxml;
    
 --modify xml, replace the text of GroupKey element whose text equals @oldGroupKeyValue with @newGroupKeyValue
 --if newGroupKeyValue is not null etc...
 SET @xml.modify('
   replace value of (/PWR_ViewAll/dgvViewAll_Vertical/GroupKey[.=sql:variable("@oldGroupKeyValue")]/text())[1]  
   with sql:variable("@newGroupKeyValue") 
 '
 );
    
 SELECT @xml AS newxml;
    
 --update #tmpData set xmldata = @xml where ID=1;
 --select * from #tmpData;
    
 DROP TABLE #tmpData
```

Comment: I really don't follow what you are asking here, as there's isn't actually a question in the above. What isn't working in the code you have above, as it does appear to do what it asks.

Comment: the code i have given here working but many charindex() used in stuff function that area not clear. anyone can tell me why so many charindex used there.

Comment: i already mention which area not clear to me in this post. `Especially this area is not clear`

Comment: So do you not understand what `CHARINDEX` does? Have you had a look at the documentation on the function, which explains its behaviour?

Comment: i know what CHARINDEX does but if you see the code then must notice that so many CHARINDEX used there which confuse me.